Why was Russia's transition into capitalism so horrible and filled with suffering for the people?
I have recently found out that Russia had around 1000% inflation during the 90s. Obviously, it seems related to the fall of communism.
However, I also realized that China's transition to capitalism was far softer, and now they seem to go along well.
I was wondering why was it so harsh for Russians ?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s).  I did a quick Google search on the title question and there are multiple answers in the first five results.  Before we replicate research that you've already done, could you summarize why the standard answers are insufficient?

e.g. "Until the end of 1991 the Soviet Union was formally still one country, but it had ceased to function as such. The initial conditions for the economic transition in Russia were awful: near hyperinfla- tion, almost complete shortages, international default, depleted international reserves, and output in free fall." Peterson

If Russia hadn't transitioned to capitalism, would things have been different under a bankrupt communist state?

I don't think you may compare a state that has gone to capitalism in a traumatic way (with tanks in the roads) vs a state that had (and has) a strong central government

I think the reason for the confusion behind the question here is that a simple "transition to capitalism" is not a sufficient way to describe what what was happening in Russia at the time.

And even if we do accept that Russia experienced a "transition to capitalism" in the 1990s, how does that concept apply to China, which remains a one-party state with a massive ownership stake in the economy? Voting to close.

In nutshell: this can be traced to Ryzhkov's attempted reform of 1987 and collapse oil prices (as the result of Saudi's action from 1986). These two factors make it very different from other countries.

NOTE: As JMS points out this question is also based on a false premise - that China transitioned easily

Triple (or worse) digit inflation is what we call Hyperinflation, and it is (almost?) always caused by the government (over)"printing money".
There are often some other societal problems that induce a government to overprint money (the website I linked goes into some), but I'd daresay one condition is that the government isn't being run with much real competence and/or accountability, because frankly it takes work to overprint money to this extent, and its a dumb thing to do.
The technical economic term is "increasing the money supply". It can be a tempting to solution to the government not having much money to work with, because its not a lot of work, and as cheap as paper. However, money is on a supply/demand curve like any other commodity. If you drastically increase the supply, without changing anything else, then the actual value of any one unit of it drops. This hurts everyone who is holding any of it, which discourages holding any of it, which causes more inflation...
But the basic point here is that it didn't have (much) to do with "converting to capitalism". It had a lot more to do with their government being run by people who either didn't know what they were doing, or didn't care.
In this specific case, according to Dr. Thayer Watkins at San Diego State, the culprit was the Russian Central Bank, under the guidance of a Communist die-hard who didn't actually want to transition to a modern Capitalist system at all, and was bascially acting like it wasn't happening.

The head of the Central Bank of Russia was Viktor Gerashchenko. He was
a dedicated Communist and, as such, not at all interested in having
the Russian economy make a smooth transition from the Stalinist system
to some version of a private market economy. Most of the State
Enterprises of the Soviet Union operated at a deficit; i.e., the ruble
value of their products was less than the ruble costs of the labor and
raw materials that went into producing them. Under the old system the
state covered the difference. During the transition the government of
Russia stopped covering those deficits. The enterprises were then
faced with a choice of cutting costs, shutting down or finding some
other way to cover the deficit. The only feasible way to cover their
costs was to get loans from the Central Bank. The financial system in
Russia was complicated and enigmatic but in a simpler system the
effects of those loans would have worked as follows. The loans were in
the form of accounts granted at the central bank. In a fractional
reserve banking system accounts at the central bank are high powered
money. The total money supply expands by a multiple of the amount of
those central bank accounts granted. When the money supply expands in
excess of the real growth of the economy there is an increase in the
price level -- inflation. In the case of Russia at the time there was
no real growth in the economy, it was in fact contracting. If the
money supply expands 5 percent and production is contracting 20
percent this is an expansion of the money supply by about 25 percent
per unit of output and there would be correspondingly high impact on
the price level. When inflation develops the velocity of money
increases and thus the impact on the rate of inflation is due to the
sum of the rate of growth of the money supply and the rate of increase
of the velocity of money. Thus prices are hit by a triple whammy of
expanding money supply, decreasing output and increasing money
velocity. This is how inflation rates can be driven to astronomical
levels.


They are not really all that comparable.
China, for better or worse, kept the CCP in power and, under its direction, gradually and organically liberalized their economy, from a very low base and sold cheap manufactured goods to a West eager for those goods and receptive to both the economic potential of the Chinese market as well as the benefits of further decoupling China from Russia.  Chinese culture, and attitudes towards trade and entrepreneurship may also differ substantially from Russian culture, which did not only inherit the legacy of the Soviets but also really did not have a great inspiration to draw on from the feudalism of Tsarist times.
It also helped that Deng Xiaoping, who effected this policy change was rather pragmatic on economics when compared to China's current Xi Jinping.

it doesn't matter if a cat is black or white, as long as it catches mice

Russia imploded from Communism in a rather unplanned fashion and did not develop a significant manufactured goods export capability.  For a while the oligarchs were running the show and no one really seemed in charge while corruption ran rampant.  Industry, hitherto largely focused on military gear, collapsed, from a not-great starting point, to a much lower one, as a result of the transition.  The gains from resource-focused exports tended to get funneled to a much smaller base of oligarchs, rather than into the economy as a whole.
This is what got Putin elected, but he just took charge of the corruption once in power and still did not manage to diversify from oil once in power, while consumers preferred Western goods, if they could afford them.
Unlike China, the West had limited interest in Russia's market and more or less had a policy of benign neglect.  Not that it was all that obvious what could have been done as aid tended to get siphoned off into corruption schemes. What advice was given, such as the mass privatization voucher scheme, ended up benefiting the oligarchs more than the overall economy.
In hindsight, we probably should have done more, it probably would have been a very worthwhile investment, but people were just happy for the Cold War to be over, and unwilling to forego the benefits of reduced defense spending by going into large scale foreign aid to their past adversary.  Plus, Eastern Europe had massive aid requirements of their own.

"Russia imploded from Communism" - neither of those terms are correct. Russia went through great troubles to stay together (despite the best efforts of Tatarstan and Chechnya) and the USSR never achieved communism


Question:
Why was Russia's transition into capitalism so horrible and filled with suffering for the people?

Short Answer:
Any economic reform / restructuring is fought with short term economic peril.  How bad is a factor of:

how ambitious the reform
how long you have to reform
how strong the economy
how good the plan
how quickly your leaders change course after they identify execution problems in that plan.

Russia had very ambitious reforms to tackle, very little time to tackle them, a weak post-Soviet economy, and initially a poor plan.  They did have leaders able to recognize problems and change course.  Given that they are far from the worst example of such a transition even with the fact their short transition time and scope of reform, makes it one of the most ambitious.  The floor of any Russian economic fall is higher than most given all the economic assets, raw materials and strong exports, the Russian economy is blessed with.
Answer:
The Soviet Union publicly had nominal inflation.  They accomplished this by controlling the market and maintaining artificially low prices to the consumer.  Despite the benefits, the reason why this is not a widely adopted policy among more conservative economies is because it's a formula for shortages, as it was in the Soviet Union.  When there is a shortage of a consumer good, allowing the price to go up suppresses consumer demand while incentivizing manufactures to increase capacity.
The result of these unconstrained shortages in Russia encouraged an ever increasing reliance an unregulated and unmonitored black market for supplying goods.  After the fall of the Soviet Union Dec 25, 1991, production which to that point was owned by the state faltered, shortages got worse, the previously price-controlled goods were no more, and consumers were now entirely reliant upon the unregulated black market they could not afford.  This led to large increases in prices which the consumer could not afford for even the bare staples. The plan for mitigating the increasing costs to the consumer was to print more money, get more money into the economy, and hopefully in the hands of the struggling consumer.  This led to peak inflation in Russia of 2,500% in 1992.  The consumer could afford to pay more, but the shortages remained, so the retailers continued to raise their prices.  A formula for hyper-inflation.
In 1992 Russia's money supply had grown 18 times, directly giving rise to the inflation.

Economic history of the Russian Federation
By the end of 1992, the Russian money supply had increased by eighteen times. This led directly to high inflation and to a deterioration in the exchange rate of the ruble.

Suffice it to say economies always struggle with big changes.  The more ambitious the change the more the people will struggle.  With Russia economic reform was forced upon them with the economic and political collapse of the Soviet Union.  They were in reaction mode early on and that lead to poor decisions. They had to sell off their public means of production, while they were trying to reform their markets.  They didn't have a choice because their production cost them money to run they didn't have.  The Soviet days left them having too much of one product and not enough of others and none of the production capacity was related to consumer demand.  Coupled with the fact their consumers were used to paying an artificially low price for goods.  Fixing all of those things along with their entire financial system while broke is what lead to their rough transition to capitalism, including the hyperinflation of 1992.
A more extreme story of economic reform than Russia would have to be China.  15 to 45 million people died in their Great Leap Forward (1958-1962), as they tried to become more economically competitive.  They might say they did not experience the hyper-inflation Russia did, largely because China maintained their price controls and systemically altered economic numbers which were not flattering; however, there is no doubt that the Chinese peopled suffered mightily in this misguided attempt at economic reform. Famine and shortages ravaged the country and killed millions.
It wasn't until the 1980's that China adopted a better plan, a gradualist approach in its post-Mao reforms, maintaining central control over key sectors while slowly liberalizing others. This approach avoided the severe dislocations seen in Russia.  Russia in 1991 simple didn't have decades to implement gradual reform.
